# PhoneGap Windows Phone 8 - Access ressource from www/ folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a PhoneGap project on Windows Phone 8.
I can't find a solution to access a ressource located in `www/` folder at runtime from my javascript.

My project looks like :

```
- www/
 `- css/
 `- js/
   `- main.js
   `- data1.json
   `- data2.json
 `- index.html
```

In my script `main.js` I want to load either `data1.json` or `data2.json`.

I have try many solutions which doesn't works :

**AJAX function from jquery**

```
this.op = (function() {
  var val = null;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'www/js/data1.json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('DATA: ' + data);
      val = JSON.parse(data);
    }
  });
  return val;
})();
```

**[File plugin sample](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) from PhoneGap**

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("js/data1.json", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

I also tried to inspect the file system by using a function to list directories from root filesystem which lead me to something like :

```
`- /
  `- __Application Settings
  `- Microsoft
    `- Internet Explorer
      `- DCOM
  `- Shared
    `- Media
    `- ShellContent
    `- Transfers
```

Any of these folders lead to the `www/` or to my bundle. I can't find a way to load my `*.json` files dynamically.

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: try removing www folder from $.ajax url ie  "js/data1.json" or "/js/data1.json" try both

Comment: Thx for your help but I tried every single combination and any of them did work :/

Comment: try placing data.json and data2.json on the same level as index.html and then change url to 'data1.json' or '/data1.json'

Comment: It also doesn't work :(

Comment: have you made the file as resource? right click on the file and make them resources. so that when you complite them then they are copied on to phone. try that

Comment: I made it as "Content" in Visual Studio as well as other source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was the usage of relatives path to access my files.

I was using a plugin of requireJS to include my file however this plugin created ridiculous relatives path to my file like  `app/../js/data1.json`.

It works well now.

EDIT: I changed the compute of the path in the plugin to remove useless directory changes like so :

```
app/../js/data1.json
```

becomes

```
js/data1.json
```

Just a substring was enought cause every path was compute the same way.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about how you modified your code to solve the issue?